# English name of “Marmalin” (Spanish) tomato cultivar

Tags: identification, tomatoes, cultivar

Ten days ago I've seen in a fruit shop some tomatoes named "Tomate Marmalin" in Spanish. The "Marmalin" word might be Catalan though. I can't find anything on internet about this variety, not even in Spanish. Does anyone know anything about this variety? I wonder if it has a name in English.

[image: Foto1]

Answer (score 3):

This looks like one of the [Beefsteak Tomato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beefsteak_tomato).

Probably the [**Marmande** tomato](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tomates_Marmande.jpg); and its closely related to the name you give it in Spanish.

[This at *Dave's Garden.com*](https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/thumbnail.php?image=2015/05/23/stephanietx/43d39c.jpg&widht=700&height=312) seems to confirm with nice picture:

[image]

Hope it helps and *bon appétit*